# How to use express routing with angular 10 routing?

Tags: angular, express

I'm new to express and angular. I'm currently using angular cli 10.0.2 and express v4.17.

I have built a very simple app and trying to learn login/logout using MSAL. I'm able to login using MSAL and also logout, with `postLogoutRedirectUri: 'logout'` where `logout` is an angular component. Instead of showing me the logout html from the component, I get `{"error":{"status":404}}` which I think is from express.

*express*

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //console.log(res);
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

*angular*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    component: LogoutComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    //component: AppComponent,
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }]
```

Can somebody please help me understand what's going on with express and angular underneath that it cannot find the angular component?

Comment: Turn on enableTracing to see if the route is recognized: from Docs:
https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions. After enabling it, see the angular router events from the developers in the console.

Comment: Express routes are server-side only.

Comment: @Brandon, I understand that. But what I"m struggling with is when I click a link, say 'admin', the route becomes `localhost:3000/admin` which express doesn't know how to handle. That's what I'm trying to understand and figure out - how to let express know that it's an angular route and hand it off to angular to deal with it.

Comment: That’s not how Angular works. Once your Angular app is loaded in the browser, all of it’s routing is client-side.

Comment: @Brandon, that's very helpful. So, then how do I make express understand that when user logs out using MSAL, there's a `postLogoutRedirectUri` which contains the angular router. Is there a way to make that work? Or do you think the only possible way is to create a logout html page that express can find?

Comment: You can't, however, if your app leverages Angular Universal, meaning, your Angular app is served by Node/Express. You can probably set the `window.location` to your logout route, and Express should be able to render the Angular app using that route as the starting point.